# php strings with <>s in them seem to need escaping

Tags: php, string, escaping, angle, brackets

I've got this down to a two line php file:

> ```
>    $s = "<option value=\"%id%\">%desc%</option>";
>    die($s);
> ```

This will output:

> %desc%

If I change the <>s to `& l t ; & g t ;`
then it works but the string I am trying to output is to be interpreted as HTML.

I don't see anything in the PHP string docs to indicate that <>s are special characters that need escaping.
Funny thing is, I have the same problem happening when trying to quote the problem in this forum!
Whats the deal?

Comment: They are html special characters, not php's one. Look at the page body. PS: 20 years of programming experience in MS and cannot debug yet... it's just amazing

Comment: Escaping is all about context. You need to elaborate on that. Else it's difficult to tell why the default HTML *context* behaviour is unexpected in your case. -- Also, Stackoverflow allows a limited set of HTML in its Wiki/Markdown parser. It's by design.

Comment: Figured it out.
The charset was the problem.
I added a meta tag to set the charset="UTF-8" and all is well.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting the correct output to your browser, that is

```
<option value=\"%id%\">%desc%</option>
```

However, your browser is then parsing this as HTML. You can confirm this by viewing the raw HTML source.

If you do not want your browser to parse it as HTML, use `&lt;` and `&gt;`.